# How to use MAX and TOP in SQL Query in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Suppose I have following table

```
ID   ITEM   QUANTITY   DATE
1    A      50         Jan 3, 2013
2    B      80         Jan 1, 2013
3    C      70         Jan 5, 2013
4    D      80         Jan 4, 2013
```

I have to make a single query which will fetch the record which has highest quantity and highest date. For example, end result should be

```
4    D    80   Jan 4, 2013
```

**Update:** First of all I have to pick the records which have highest quantity. In this case it would be record no. 2 and 4. Then I have to again filter out from these two records which have highest date

How should I make SQL query in ORACLE?

Comment: Date of item 4 is less than date of item 3. Clarify your requirements.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov - First of all I have to pick the records which have highest quantity. In this case it would be record no. 2 and 4. Then I have to again filter out from these two records which have highest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those data you could write a query similar to this one:

```
select id
     , item
     , quantity
     , date
  from (select id
             , item
             , quantity
             , date
          from your_table
         order by quantity desc, date desc
        )
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Yes, it works - thanks - I was thinking that I would have to use MAX and TOP keywords here. But this is very simple approach.